# Adding a script file in a Visual Studio 2010 C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resource-files

I am writing a C# program that needs to run a script. I want to include the script with the application so that it is available when the user installs the program after I publish it.

I tried adding the script as a resource. In the Solution Explorer, under the Resources directory, I can see the script file.

In the program, I call a function that starts a process and runs the desired command:

```
runNewProcess("tclsh \\Resources\\make.tcl " + activeProducts);
```

I get the command prompt with the message "couldn't read file "\Resources\make.tcl": no such file or directory". So I guess it cannot find the file? Am I not referencing the file correctly? Is this the correct way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Using them and with a bit more research, I was able to come up with a perfect solution for me.

1) Add the TCL script file as a resource to the project and set the Build Action to 'Content' in it's Properties.

2) Get the path to the TCL script (even after installation from a published version):

```
string makeScriptPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\make.tcl";
```

3) Construct the run command using all the required variables and pass it to a routine that can execute it.

```
localCommand = String.Format("tclsh \"{0}\" --librarytype {1} --makeclean {2} --buildcode {3} --copybinary {4} --targetpath \"{5}\" --buildjobs {6} --products {7}",
                                       makeScriptPath, library, makeClean, buildCode, copyBinary, targetPath, buildJobs, activeProducts);
                runNewProcess(localCommand);
```

where:

```
    private void runNewProcess(string command)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k " + command);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
    }
```

This gives some added perks. Since the file is included with the application, but remains a separate entity, this allows it to be tweaked and modified without needing to re-build, re-publish and re-install the application.

Answer (score 1):

The script runner is unable to dig into you executable to find the commands, as it most likely only know what to do with files on disk. Shipping as a resource is a good idea, but for make anything useful with it you should extract it into a real file on disk so that other programs can use it.

A good pattern for such things would be to create a temporary file on %TEMP%, make the script runner execute that file, and delete it afterwards.

Comment: I see. Could you please expand on how one would go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Alejandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109610/80274), The easiest way to handle this is to use the temporary folder and copy your script there first.

```
var scriptPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "make.tcl");

// Copy the text of the script to the temp folder. There should be a property 
//you can reference associated with the script file if you added the file using 
//the resources tab in the project settings. This will have the entire script in
//string form.
File.WrteAllText(scriptPath, Resources.make);

runNewProcess("tclsh \"" + scriptPath + "\"" + activeProducts); //added quotes in case there are spaces in the path to temp.

File.Delete(scriptPath); //Clean up after yourself when you are done.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `Build Action` of the script file is set to `Content` to keep it as an independent file. By default it will be set to `Resource` which means you will have to programmatically extract it and then save it to a temporary location before attempting to run it.

Comment: OK, I have changed the Build Action to contnet but I still get the same message. Am I accessing it correctly?

Comment: Problem with setting to `Content` is that you have to handle 2 files instead of only one. With a `Resource`, the script is bundled inside the .exe, so deploying becomes easier.